# How to copy sections of a document

Tags: wordpad

I want to copy the timecode which is on the right side of this document

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start with the top or whichever cell you want, hold Shift + down arrow. Looks like you've got a merged row of cells so it'll also copy that one as you go down, I don't think that's avoidable